# IE8 showModalDialog does not set referer in the request header

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-8, http-referer

We are writing some javascript to override methods window.open and window.showModalDialog the the referer will be set in the header.

```
if (isIE) {
    if (!window.__open) {
      window.__open = window.open;
      window.open = function (url, name, features) {
        this.__ESSecurity.alert("my window.open");
        var ww = window.__open("", name, features);
        ww.location.href = url;
        return ww;
      };
    }    

    if (!window.__showModalDialog) {
      window.__showModalDialog = window.showModalDialog;
      window.showModalDialog = function (url, obj, features) {
        this.__ESSecurity.alert("my window.showModalDialog");

        var Hfeatures = this.__ESSecurity.splitFeatures(features);
        var features = 'left=' + Hfeatures['dialogLeft'] + ',top='+ Hfeatures['dialogTop'];
        features+= ',width=' + Hfeatures['dialogWidth']  + ',height=' + Hfeatures['dialogHeight'];
        features+= ',toolbar=no,menubar=no,status=no,resizable=yes,modal=yes';
        var ww =  window.open(url, "name", features);
        return ww;
    };
}
```

}
It works fine in FF and IE9 but only in IE8 the method showModalDialog is not passing the referer.

Do you have any idea what might be missing?

Comment: So what? The referrer is notoriously unreliable – so if this particular instance of it “not working” is a problem for your application … then fix your application.

Comment: The referrer is necessary to my application in order to navigate, this is how it is already done i can't change it, and we need it to works on IE8, i appreciate if someone can help.